# Spotify gift card countries not matching

Tags: spotify

My father has bought me a gift card from Spotify, from Belgium. I'm from Belgium, but I spend most of my time in the Netherlands, so I usually pay for Spotify with a Dutch credit card. Now, when I try to redeem my gift card, Spotify tells me that you can only redeem gift cards from the same country as the gift card was bought. I'm currently accessing Spotify from a Belgian IP address, but my account's country is still set to the Netherlands.

[image]

To update my country, it tells me I need to change my payment details.

[image]

When I click that link, it asks me to select a plan, but since I've just received 3 months of Spotify, I don't want to pay for another Spotify plan, and I don't have a Belgian credit card. Is there a way to change your country without making a purchase?

[The Spotify help question about changing your country](https://support.spotify.com/us/learn-more/faq/#!/article/How-can-I-change-my-country-setting) says that the country selection field should only be greyed out if your IP address matches your country. Because the Netherlands and Belgium are so close together, I used a VPN to change my location to the US, but the dropdown is still grey.